# Is there a way to discourage premature answers?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395043/showing-surjectivity-of-a-certain-function) and some others I've seen leave me feeling that one should help the person understand what a question says rather than helping them answer it.  Maybe after meeting with success at helping them understand it one should see if they consequently emend the question, and then answer the later form of the question, if any still remains.  But some people rush in and post an answer within a minute, which is "accepted" within two minutes.  Is there some way to retard such premature solutions?

Comment: In addition, I see a lot of detailed answers (by newbies and non-newbies alike) being posted to questions that show no effort whatsoever from the part of the OP. To me, that only encourages people to ask homework questions and such because they know someone here will give them the answer on a silver platter. Along with retarding people's answer triggers, I wonder if there are ways to educate the community to try and get people asking questions to do more of the thinking by themselves.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391963/coordinates-rotated-90-degrees-clockwise) is a typical example.

Comment: You are free to vote down such answers, and/or to leave a comment expressing your objections, Michael. I have done this from time to time. Whether it has any effect, well, I don't know, but I don't know of anything short of sending the boys around that's very likely to have an effect.

Comment: There is also some rush to mark duplicates and close, so people could we answering fast in order to enter before the question is closed.

Comment: I sometimes see people commenting on questions with the canned message "What have you tried?" I don't think I've ever seen anyone comment on an answer "@OP You do understand why this answer is correct?"

Comment: I think this behavior is a lack of restraint perhaps exacerbated by the Q&A and reputation point format of MSE. Some users are *much* too eager to "take the wheel". This is essentially a question of how to encourage people to answer questions more pedagogically. Can this be done *only* through up/down voting?